# scheduler library is not working with function-based view in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

`I am working on functional based view in django and I want to schedule a task for every few minutes. I am scheduling task using "schedule" library [pip install schedule]. when i am executing the task i am getting an error as :  TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'.

If i try to pass some string in request parameter I get error as : AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'META'

what shall i pass in "request" parameter ?`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json
import schedule
import time

def home(request):
    print("Scheduler working")
    res = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").json()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'res':res})


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(home)
#TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'


#schedule.every(5).seconds.do(home(request=True)
#AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'META' (if try to pass some parameter such as string or bool or int)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the schedule package, since I use celery beat and celery tasks for handling background workers and their scheduling.

The error will continue to occur because you cant access request in that way. You're ways to schedule tasks are: Using a management command and schedule it via a crontab, celery + celery beat or django-q. There are probably more alternatives, but those are the best ones for you're case.

Edit: Here is a good reference for understanding request and responses:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/